# How to implement aiml using java

Tags: java, c#, artificial-intelligence, aiml

I was planning to make a chat bot as my project.
i understood basic aiml tags but i am not getting how to implement aiml tags. Also how can we create GUI for this chatbot

Comment: Did you find any solution? i am on the same problem.

Comment: i implemented chatbot using program # . It is also opensource program.
program # provides a dll file aimlBot.dll which has to be referenced in our project.
aimlBot library provides classes to parse the aiml files and get responss from the files we created
follow this link for more information
http://ntoll.org/program-an-aiml-chatterbot-in-c.html

Answer (score 5):

If you are wanting an AIML chatbot in Java, then you should check out [Program D](http://aitools.org/Program_D).  It's open source so if you don't want to use it yourself, at least you will be able to get some ideas on how to implement an AIML parser.

There are also many more parsers in different languages which can be found at [Alicebot.org](http://www.alicebot.org/downloads/programs.html), which is also a good resource for all things A.I. and AIML.

Answer (score 4):

[ProgramAB](https://code.google.com/p/program-ab) is an open source AIML 2.0 interpreter written in Java. It also comes with additional features like automated pattern suggestor and a rule generator.